# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a project with Angular. 
When I try to run my app with `IIS 8`, I get the below error in my console & page does not appear.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app
>   due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

But when I run my app in local it works fine. I'm using `gulp build` to build my app for IIS.

I researched in many blogs including Stack overflow but yet unable to figure it out the problem.

I've tried to move script tags, re-checked all spelling mistakes but none worked for me. I slightly get a doubt whether the build is not done 100% over gulp.

I've given my `index.html` file & `app.js` file below. Please advise me where I have done any mistake.

#### app.module.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', [
        'triangular',
        'ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngMaterial',
        'ui.router', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'LocalStorageModule', 
'googlechart', 'chart.js', 'linkify',
        'ui.calendar', 'angularMoment', 'textAngular', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps', 
'hljs', 'md.data.table',
        angularDragula(angular), 'ngFileUpload', 'ngProgress',
        //'app.examples',
        'roadrunner'
    ])
    // create a constant for languages so they can be added to both 
triangular & translate
    .constant('APP_LANGUAGES', [{
        name: 'LANGUAGES.CHINESE',
        key: 'zh'
    },{
        name: 'LANGUAGES.ENGLISH',
        key: 'en'
    },{
        name: 'LANGUAGES.FRENCH',
        key: 'fr'
    },{
        name: 'LANGUAGES.PORTUGUESE',
        key: 'pt'
    }])
    // set a constant for the API we are connecting to
    .constant('API_CONFIG', {
        'url':  'http://triangular-api.oxygenna.com/'
    })
    .run(function (auth, $rootScope, $state, $mdToast, ngProgressFactory) {

        auth.tryRestoreSession();

        var progressbar = ngProgressFactory.createInstance();

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, 
toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            //!auth.checkAuth(); // check for null $rootScope.user 
            //!toState.freeAccess; // check for no freeAccess state

            progressbar.setColor("rgb(156,39,176)");
            progressbar.start();                
            //progressbar.set(40);

            if (toState.freeAccess !== true && !auth.checkAuth()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('authentication.login');
            }
            if (toState.name == 'authentication.login') {
                if (auth.checkAuth()) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $state.go(fromState.name !== "" ? fromState.name : 
'triangular-no-scroll.student.profile');
                    $mdToast.show({
                        template: '<md-toast class="md-toast 
success">Already logged in</md-toast>',
                        hideDelay: 3000,
                        position: 'top right'
                    })
                }
            }
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, 
toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            progressbar.complete();
        });
    })
})();
```

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Triangular</title>

<!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js">
</script>....

<!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="app/modules/student/common/student.common.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/student/common/models/student.model.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>...
```

#### bower.js

```
gulp.task('bower', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('bower:build');
});

gulp.task('bower:build', ['bower:scripts', 'bower:styles',
  'bower:scripts:minify', 'bower:styles:minify']);

gulp.task('bower:scripts', ['bower:partials'], function () {
  return gulp.src([
    path.join(paths.src, '/app/triangular/**/*.js'),
    path.join(paths.tmp, 'partials', 'templateCacheHtml.js')
  ])
    .pipe($.angularFilesort())
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.concat('triangular.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/'));
});
```

Comment: Narrow down your problem, post only relevant code here, Where have you added the reference to _app.js_?

Comment: If it works locally, but not after the Gulp build, there must be something wrong with the build process. Developer console network tab showing any errors loading your JS files?

Comment: @M.Ammar I dont think so you have added a reference to app.js

Comment: @Satpal As per console, It refers that Module App is not loading properly due to some mistake. Either a spelling mistake or the order of the scripts is incorrect. But I've rechecked both of these as per my knowledge but unable to figure it out. I get a blank web page with above console error.

Comment: have you even included `app.js`?

Comment: Yes i have added `app.js` in script tags.

Comment: @AndrewR I was thinking the same thing. No errors on Network tab it loads fine.

Comment: The app.js file you posted here is incomplete. I'm guessing the real version has more to it?

Comment: There are a couple reasons I can think of that will cause a `Failed to instantiate module ` message. Either the file isn't loaded, or syntax errors in the file cause it to not load.

Comment: your gulp code should be written in such a way that, `app.js` loads on the top of all the remaining scripts. paste the `index.html` and the `gulp task for build`.

Comment: @AndrewR I've updated the complete `app.module.js`. The file is loaded via script tag.

Comment: where is `index.html` ?

Comment: @Sravan `index.html` & `gulp task for build` is updated.

Comment: Shouldn't the "triangular & translate" be a comment in your app.js?

Comment: @MarcusH It is a comment already

Comment: @M. Ammar, to which file the error is pointing to?

Comment: @Sravan to `vendor.js`

Comment: just move, `<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>` in index.html to top and check

Comment: I checked but the result is same. Top means top of custom scripts or above the `bower components` scripts?